# I would like to create a measure in powerBI that is the standard deviation of distinct count by month

Tags: powerbi, dax, standard-deviation

I would like to create a measure in powerBI that is the standard deviation of the distinct counts of IDs by month. i.e:
for this data set:

```
Month | ID
1       A
1       B
1       A
2       C
2       D
2       E
3       F
3       G

The Counts would be:
Month | Distinct Count
1       2
2       3
3       2
```

Standard Dev = 0.47

Thank you!!!!!

Below is an iteration of the code I tried that hasn't worked:

```
standard dev by month = STDEVX.P(values('Table'[Reporting Date By Month Year]), DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID]))
```

Comment: You'll want [`STDEVX.S`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/stdevx-s-function-dax) or [`STDEVX.P`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/stdevx-p-function-dax). Please update your question to show the code that you've tried already, showing the results you're seeing, and highlighting where your difficulties are, and we can help you out. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @greggyb, I updated the post to one of the iterations I tried.  I'm new to posting on stackoverflow and apologize for giving the impression I was used the forum as a "code writing service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the table you provided named as "Table" you can use the following measure to get the standard deviation.

```
Standard Deviation = 

var grouped_table = SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[Month],"Distinct Count",DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID]))

var st_dev = STDEVX.P(grouped_table,[Distinct Count])

return(st_dev)
```

The measure uses variables to make the measure more easy to read. The first table generates the group of months and the respective distinct count of IDs. The second variables calculated the standard deviation of that table by distinct count measure.

Comment: Thank you so much @Angelo Canepa! This worked perfectly and gave me a much better understanding on how to code in DAX more effectively.